# Method "xxx" is not defined for the type "xxx". The error occures even though the method is defined

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
int selectedContactID;
String selectedContactName;

class Variables {

  static _getContactName() {
    return selectedContactName;
  }

  static _setContactName(String s) {
    selectedContactName = s;
  }

}
```

For whatever reason calling the functions use the method below

```
Variables._setContactName("e");
```

Returns the error: The method '_setContactName' isn't defined for the type 'Variables'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named '_setContactName'.

Which seems utterly ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally an underline before a method name defines the method as private, have you tried defining the method without the _ e.g. static getContactName()?